# Video is unavailable for pick in android

Tags: android

I use gallery to choose video and images from phone and load them to application.
I use code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
} else {
    photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
}
```

Everything is ok, but when I go in Internal storage/DCIM I can pick only images. Video files are grey and I can't pick them. Any ideas?

Comment: you didn't get videos if used sdk less than 19.

Comment: I had this issue on android 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code resolve my problem:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)), SELECT_GALLERY);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_GALLERY_KITKAT);
}
```

this line:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private static final int VIDEO_GALLERY_REQUEST = 2;
Uri video_uri;

addVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("video/");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,VIDEO_GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == VIDEO_GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == -1){
        video_uri = data.getData();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting Intent :

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT);
```

Check For you video and Image :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();

    if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("images")) {
        //Your image
    } else  if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("video")) {
        //Your video
    }
}
```